# Will batsman caught out if ball touches body first?

Tags: rules, cricket

If ball touches body first then bat and caught, will batsman be considered out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, he will be out caught - see [Law 32](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-32-caught-1/)